# Como vincular correctamente los archivos de Drupal con docker-compose para salvarlos en mi maquina local

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal

así configuré los volumenes en mi docker-compose.yml

```
   volumes:
     - ./drupal/modules:/opt/drupal/modules
     - ./drupal/profiles:/opt/drupal/profiles
     - ./drupal/sites:/opt/drupal/sites
     - ./drupal/themes:/opt/drupal/themes
```

y la instalación de drupal se **completa con exito**, sin embargo el cms no guarda los archivo en "/opt/drupal/sites" sino en "**/opt/drupal/web/sites**".
Ahora si cambio las rutas por "/opt/drupal/web/..." en docker-compose.yml, la instalación de drupal me dice que necesita los archivos default.settings.php y settings.php.

Tampoco entiendo porqué en la doc de la imagen de drupal recomiendan usar la ruta "/var/www/html/..." esto me da el mismo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la [documentacion de la imagen oficial](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal), para mantener el contenido persistente de la manera mas simple se puede usar volumenes anonimos apuntando a las carpetas en `/var/www/html`:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:8-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      - /var/www/html/sites
    restart: always
```

Notese que `/var/www/html` es un alias a la carpeta `/opt/drupal/web`, por lo tanto ambas referencias pueden ser válidas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Naturalmente si deseas que estos archivos queden disponibles localmente puedes engancharlos con una ruta local. Si estas rutas existen localmente pero estan vacias, la carpeta del contenedor se sobreescribira con ella.

```
volumes:
  - ./drupal/modules:/var/www/html/modules
  - ./drupal/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
  - ./drupal/themes:/var/www/html/themes
  - ./drupal/sites:/var/www/html/sites
```

Si creas un link local a `sites` pasará lo que indicas en el problema, ya que la carpeta estara vacia al iniciar la imagen, ya que tu copia local esta vacia y sobreescribe a la existente en la imagen (las demas pueden estar vacias y no hay problema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionarlo hice un Dockerfile y un script para ejecutar la primera vez

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  drupal:
    build: ./
    image: drupal-8-apache
    links:
        - "mysql:mysql"
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    volumes:
      - ./modules:/opt/drupal/web/modules
      - ./profiles:/opt/drupal/web/profiles
      - ./themes:/opt/drupal/web/themes
      - ./sites:/opt/drupal/web/sites
    restart: always
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./database:/database
    environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
```

**startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e /opt/drupal/web/sites/README.txt ]; then
    cp -R /tmp/web /opt/drupal/
fi
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM drupal:8-apache

COPY startup.sh /opt/drupal/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/drupal/startup.sh
RUN cp -R /opt/drupal/web /tmp
```

Luego para iniciar por primera ve el contenedor (partiendo de la carpeta vacia):

```
# docker-compose build drupal 
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec drupal /opt/drupal/startup.sh
```

Y la carpeta sites sera llenada con el contenido por defecto, asi como las otras (que actualmente solo tienen un README.txt)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ultimo detalle, para llevar esta configuracion a otro equipo, se debe llevar las *carpetas modules, profiles, themes y sites*, en conjunto con el *respaldo de la base de datos*. Si no se respalda y restaura la base de datos se obtendra un mensaje como este en otro equipo o al volver a crear el contenedor (ya que la configuracion en `./sites` ya esta activa y espera una base de datos configurada).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Respaldo/restauracion de base de datos**

Notese que agregue en docker-compose.yml para el contenedor `mysql:`

```
volumes:
  - ./database:/database
```

Para respaldar la base de datos puedes ejecutar un comando de respaldo de base de datos (`mysqldump`) sobre el contenedor mysql:

```
docker-compose exec mysql mysqldump -u root -prootpass --opt drupal -r /database/backup.sql
```

Esto dejara un backup en la carpeta remota `/database/backup.sql` (que localmente es `./database/backup.sql`)

Y luego para restaurar la base de datos en otro equipo o cuando desees volver la base de datos al momento del respaldo:

```
docker-compose exec mysql mysql -u root -prootpass -e 'source /database/backup.sql' drupal
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @F.Igor. Tu respuesta me ayudó mucho.
Me puedes confirmar si para llevarme el proyecto ya inicializado a otra computadora solo tengo que copiar los volumenes locales y ejecuta docker-compose up -d.
Nota: también tengo un volumen local para la base de datos.

Comment: Una vez que ya tengas configurado el proyecto, incluyes las carpetas, pero tambien se debe obtener un respaldo de la base de datos para que sea completo. En la otra maquina solo mantienes las carpetas y restauras la BD. Voy a agregar eso en el ejemplo ya que es parte del proceso.